# What does a zero random effect estimate mean in lmer/glmer in R, and is there an official reference for it?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

In R in lmer/glmer packages the model outputs give questionable values for the random effects, specifically, their Variance and S.D. are zero (0 -> and NOT 0.000). I am wondering whether this means that the random effects have no statistical effect or whether this means that their effect cannot be estimated (e.g. due to small sample size or unbalanced sample sizes across the categories of the random effect)?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you have a reproducible example? Your question is likely caused by your data. Also, your question is about interpenetrating statistics rather than programming and would probably be a better fit on Cross-Validated.

Comment: See https://rawgit.com/bbolker/mixedmodels-misc/master/glmmFAQ.html and search for "singular models" (can you please clarify what you mean by "0 -> and NOT 0.000" ?)